# How do I install the tools packages in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have installed tools but could not find a way to install tools.common.misc

I tried pip installing the modules but it did not work

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 from tools.common_misc import gen_obs, rmse_spread, createH, getBsimple
      3 from tools.common_plots import plotRMSP
      5 from tools.L63_model import lorenz63

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.common_misc'
```

Comment: how did you install tools module? By `pip install tools`?

Comment: Maybe its not a pip package, but a project folder?

Comment: This `tools` doesn't look like any common/popular packages. At least my google-fu doesn't give my any meaningful results.

Comment: I got the codes from a website for data assimilation